# How is portal ownership decided?

Tags: achievements, ingress

I have a portal where this happened:

1. Player A conquered the portal, placed one resonator. Player A was listed as owner.
2. Player B, C and D placed more resonators. B is listed as owner.

Currently there's still the one resonator from A, two resonators are from C, five resonators are from D. And two mods from B and one mod from C.

So how is portal ownership (for the Guardian badge) decided? Is the owner the player who initially conquered the portal and still has one resonator in it or can it change?

Comment: Are you sure ownership is changed to B? I've never noticed that ownership changes from the player that placed the first resonator.

Comment: @Maerlyn: Yes. It was owned by A for 24 days and is now listed as owned by B. The resonator by A has been in there for 30 days now. Probably a software problem.

Comment: Any way you could post an intel link to the portal in question?

Comment: Could it be that these players have used a virus on the portal, took it back and deployed resonators on it again? You wouldn't notice the change if you've missed the comm messages.

Comment: @EnmosProje: Highly unlikely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Portal ownership is designated by who the first person to place a resonator on the portal is. Even if all of their resonators decay, but the portal never goes unclaimed or flips teams, it will still count towards guardian days.

It is to note that the guardian badge will only count if you have resonators on a portal. Even if you have a 150+ day guardian that you own but you have no resonators, you will not get the badge until you upgrade one of the existing resonators to your own. Then the badge will pop.

As for your observation. There **has** to have been a time in which the portal was either unclaimed or the other teams. It is impossible for a portal to change ownership without changing color.

Comment: The portal in question was not unclaimed for the whole time: The resonator by A is still in there.

Comment: In the year and a half I have been playing this game, I have not once seen a portal switch ownership without switching color. This is also the observation of the comment on your question.

Comment: I've tried to submit a bug report to Niantic.

Comment: The new intel changes (portal ownership date removed) makes this almost impossible to verify.

Comment: @Mondrianaire, would you happen to know if this also means that if you flip your own guardian portal to the other color (which means either __ADA__ (if you're ENL) or __JARVIS__ (if you're RES) 'owns' the portal) and then flipping it back will still count further on for the guardian days? Or does the counter reset? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you have seen can happen if you are player A, and for a short time.

If two players of same faction place a resonator on an unclaimed portal at about the same time (no more than a few seconds delay), A may see its resonator and its name as owner on the portal, then see it switch to the other player B. That means (I suppose) that on Niantic server B was first to place the resonator, but locally on A scanner the portal status is wrong for a few seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I see in comments that there is 24 days between the two.